# react-redux-i18n switch lang

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, internationalization, jsx

I followed the readme file on this library: [url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-i18n).
Everything went fine except for a thing: how the heck can I switch the language from inside, for example, my  component?

I've tried to use an action inside my NavBar component but it returns me "this.props.dispatch" is not a function in the console.

This is my component:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logout } from '../actions/authActions';

import { Translate, Localize } from 'react-redux-i18n';
import { loadTranslations, setLocale, syncTranslationWithStore } from 'react-redux-i18n';

class NavigationBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.changeLang = this.changeLang.bind(this);
    }

    logout(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.logout();
    }

    changeLang(){
        this.props.dispatch(setLocale('nl'));
    }

    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;
        const userLinks =  (
            <a href="#" onClick={ this.logout.bind(this) }>Logout</a>
        );

        const guestLinks =  (
            <div>
                <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
                <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
            </div>
        );

        return (
            <div>
                { isAuthenticated ? userLinks: guestLinks }
                <Translate value="application.title"/>
                <br />
                <a href="#" onClick={this.changeLang}>NL</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

NavigationBar.propTypes = {
    auth: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    logout: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        auth: state.auth
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(NavigationBar);
```

Comment: "The easiest way to translate or localize in your React components is by using the Translate and Localize" - right on the docs there...

Comment: OK, but how to switch to another language, for example I have a navbar component with a link for each language!

Comment: By dispatching the setLocale('yourLAng')? Just set up an action or whatever.

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Although this is a bit old, this approach may help others:

You can use `bindActionCreators` from 'redux' to map all actions needed in a component and not worry about using `dispatch()` explicitly.

```
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

// class definition ...

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    const actions = {
        setLocale,
        // ... you can specify other actions that need dispatch here
    };
    return {
       actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch) // this will set the 'actions' property to props
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        auth: state.auth
    };
}

const connectedNavigationBar = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(NavigationBar);

export default connectedNavigationBar;
```

Now you can call the function like so: `this.props.actions.setLocale('nl');`

Your code will look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logout } from '../actions/authActions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import { Translate, Localize } from 'react-redux-i18n';
import { loadTranslations, setLocale, syncTranslationWithStore } from 'react-redux-i18n';

class NavigationBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.changeLang = this.changeLang.bind(this);
    }

    logout(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.logout();
    }

    changeLang(){
        // changed from 
        // this.props.dispatch(setLocale('nl'));
        this.props.actions.setLocale('nl');
    }

    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;
        const userLinks =  (
            Logout
        );

        const guestLinks =  (

                Signup
                Login

        );

        return (

                { isAuthenticated ? userLinks: guestLinks }



                NL

        );
    }
}

NavigationBar.propTypes = {
    auth: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    logout: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        auth: state.auth
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    const actions = {
        setLocale,
        // ... you can specify other actions that need dispatch here
    };
    return {
       actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch) // this will set the 'actions' property to props
    }
};

const connectedNavigationBar = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(NavigationBar);


export default connectedNavigationBar;
```

You can check [this](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html) for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can dispatch redux action (as shown in the [readme](https://github.com/zoover/react-redux-i18n/blob/master/README.md) example usage):

```
store.dispatch(setLocale('en'));
```

#### Update:

You can use `dispatch` inside your components with the help of [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux). Simply connect your component to redux:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const ConnectedComponent = connect()(YourComponent);
```

And dispatch will be available as a prop in the component:

```
this.props.dispatch(setLocale('en'));
```

Comment: I do that in the store file and it works, the problem is when I want to add a link in my NavBar component to change the lang... How can I let the store redespatch the setlocale event from inside the navbar?

Comment: Thanks, It gives me back an error on my console; I've edited my question!

Comment: You're on the right way. Probably when you pass an object as the second argument to `connect`, it omits to inject the `dispatch`. I don't know for sure. See the [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments) for `connect`. Try [this example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-todos-and-all-action-creators-addtodo-completetodo--as-actions). Some of those should work.